# In JSoup I am trying to get text from a span that has multiple classes with strange names the compiler is not liking

Tags: java, jsoup

Here is my code:

```
enter code heretext = text.toUpperCase();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + text + "?p=" + text).userAgent("Safari").get();

    Element temp = doc.selectFirst("span.Trsdu(0.3s).Fw(b).Fz(36px).Mb(-4px).D(ib)");

    System.out.println(temp);
```

here is the span I am trying to get:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">1,119.50</span>
```

I am new to JSoup so if i am being ignorant please let me know what i should do

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer but I can't comment yet since I don't have 50 rep points but I'd still like to help so I'll post it here.

Jsoup has a lot of issue with recognizing characters that I've also encountered.

For this particular example, I think you can use the data attribute 'data-react-id' to locate that element. First you would select all spans then the attribute, something like this doc.select("span").select("[data-react-id]=35]")

Hope that helps.